# How to add a first empty line to a select in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, select, doctrine

I'm making `createQueryBuilder` inside my `BuildForm` method to get some records from an entity.

Everything work well, I succeded to display a `select` with the data I want but I have not a first line with an empty value.

```
<select id="" name="" class="form-control">
  <option value="7">A</option>
  <option value="8">B</option>
  <option value="9">C</option>
</select>
```

And here's the code I've a made in the `BuildForm` method

```
 $builder->add('company', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Company::class,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
             return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
             ->where("c.id in {$options['id']}");
                    },
                    'label' => 'Company',
                ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `'required' => false` to the options (where you set the label)

Comment: Can be combined with like:  `'placeholder' => 'Choose a value'`

Comment: Adding a reference link to the [EntityType Field Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder) could be useful.

Comment: Better refer to `ChoiceType` because `EntityType` just inherits these properties

Answer (score 1):

You can set required => false

```
 $builder->add('company', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Company::class,

        // Here you set required to false
        'required' => false,

        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
         ->where("c.id in {$options['id']}");
                },
                'label' => 'Company',
            ));
```